# How can I use same JAXB class to marshall and unmarshall into different namespaces?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xml-serialization, xml-namespaces

**Note:** this is with Java 7.  Also, I am not using JAXB to generate anything from a schema.  I only/merely want to use JAXB to deserialize pieces of existing SOAP messages.  So the JAXB beans are "hand-written".

I am trying to deserialize the following XML with JAXB.  I do *not* have access to it as a string.  Rather, I am getting it as an `org.w3c.dom.Element` object:

```
<SynchInfo xmlns="urn:InitronSOAPService">
    <HandshakeInfo>
        <dnsName>foo.bar</dnsName>
        <ip>1.2.3.4</ip>
        <id>TheId</id>
        <key>SomeKey</key>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </HandshakeInfo>
</SynchInfo>
```

But I would also like to marshall `HandshakeInfo` instances into a `SOAPBody` that is part of a message belonging to *a different namespace*.

I first tried to write a `HandshakeInfo` class that didn't mention namespaces at all:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "HandshakeInfo")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
final private static class HandshakeInfo
{
    private String version;
    private String id;
    private String key;
    private String ip;
    private String dnsName;

    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "version")
    public void setVersion(String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "id")
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "key")
    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getIp() {
        return ip;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "ip")
    public void setIp(String ip) {
        this.ip = ip;
    }

    public String getDnsName() {
        return dnsName;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "dnsName")
    public void setDnsName(String dnsName) {
        this.dnsName = dnsName;
    }
}
```

But when I used that to try to deserialize the `Element` object containing the `HandshakeInfo` element, I got the following exception:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"urn:InitronSOAPService", local:"HandshakeInfo"). Expected elements are <{}HandshakeInfo>
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:647)
...
```

So then I tried adding `, namespace="urn:InitronSOAPService"` to all the element and attribute (in this case none) annotations in the class.  (Or, alternatively, used an `@XmlSchema` annotation in a *package-info.java* file.)  That worked for deserializing that element in that namespace.

But when I tried to use the class to serialize into a different namespace I (not entirely unexpectedly) get stuff like this:

```
<SomeMessage xmlns="urn:differentNamespace">
    <ns5:HandshakeInfo xmlns:ns5="urn:InitronSOAPService">
        <ns5:dnsName>foo.bar</ns5:dnsName>
        <ns5:ip>1.2.3.4</ns5:ip>
        <ns5:id>TheId</ns5:id>
        <ns5:key>SomeKey</ns5:key>
        <ns5:version>1.0</ns5:version>
    </ns5:HandshakeInfo>
</SomeMessage>
```

That's not what I want.  I want the serialized thing to be part of the `urn:differentNamespace`.

So is there any way to use the same JAXB class in multiple namespaces?  Or am I stuck with having to multiple copies of classes with each one annotated to be in the appropriate namespace?

I have seen some tricks using filters, etc. but those tricks seem to be assuming the XML is being read from or written to a stream or a file.  Again, for unmarshalling I am working with `org.w3c.dom.Element` objects and for marshalling I am working with `SOAPBody` objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the following options:

- Use [MOXy XML Bindings](http://eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/moxy/runtime003.htm) and move mappings out of annotations into XML resources. You could then define and load different resources for different namespaces.
- Use XSLT to preprocess XML prior to unmarshalling/postprocess after marshalling. Remapping namespaces is a trivial task in XSLT.
- Use a custom `AnnotationReader` for JAXB RI to "fake" namespace read from annotations. You just have to adjust the namespace read from the package, should not be too hard.

`AnnotationReader` solution is a bit "hacky", also ties you to JAXB RI. XML bindings would require you to rewrite your annotations in XML form and will tie you to MOXy (I think). XSLT is quite elegant but will make the processing slower. And you'll have to hack into the processing chain with your XSLT.

All the options have pros and cons, you have to carefully consider them for your specific case.